# Create object with only defined properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I have a function which returns an object with properties only which are defined.

How to refactor the function so that I don't need to make if clauses for every parameter value? There must be more elegant way to do this.

```
const getQuery = ({ foo, bar, zoo }) => {
  const query = {};

  if (foo) {
    query.foo = foo;
  }
  if (bar) {
    query.bar = bar;
  }
  if (zoo) {
    query.zoo = zoo;
  }

  return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
function getQuery(obj){
  // filter the accepted keys
  var filtered = Object.keys(obj).filter((k) => ~["foo", "bar", "baz"].indexOf(k))
  // construct new object with filtered keys
  var query = {}
  filtered.forEach((k) => query[k] = obj[k])
  return query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic function that will copy only properties provided in the wantedProps array. It will not mutate the original object.

```
let filterProperties = (originalObject = {}, wantedProps = []) => 
{
    let filteredObject = {};
    wantedProps.forEach( val => filteredObject[val] = originalObject[val] );
    return filteredObject;
}
```

If you're just trying to filter out undefined vals then you could do:

```
obj => {
   let newObject = {}
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if(obj[key] !== undefined) newObject[key] = obj[key];
   })
   return newObject;
}
```